# How can I stop a scrapy CrawlSpider and later resume where it left-off?

Tags: python, scrapy

I have a Scrapy [CrawlSpider](http://doc.scrapy.org/topics/spiders.html#crawlspider) that has a very large list of URLs to crawl. I would like to be able to stop it, saving the current status and resume it later without having to start over. Is there a way to accomplish this within the Scrapy framework?

Comment: As of Scrapy v. 0.16 Now Supports it here: http://doc.scrapy.org/en/0.16/topics/jobs.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There was a question on the ML just few months ago: http://groups.google.com/group/scrapy-users/browse_thread/thread/6a8df07daff723fc?pli=1

Quote Pablo:

> We're not only considering it, but also working on it.  There are
>   currently two working patches in my MQ that add this functionality in 
>   case anyone wants to try an early preview (they need to be applied in
>   order): 
>   http://hg.scrapy.org/users/pablo/mq/file/tip/scheduler_single_spider....
>   http://hg.scrapy.org/users/pablo/mq/file/tip/persistent_scheduler.patch
>   To run a spider as before (no persistence):
>
> ```
> scrapy crawl thespider
> ```
>
> To run a spider storing scheduler+dupefilter state in a dir:
>
> ```
> scrapy crawl thespider --set SCHEDULER_DIR=run1
> ```
>
> During the crawl, you can hit ^C to cancel the crawl and resume it
>   later with:
>
> ```
> scrapy crawl thespider --set SCHEDULER_DIR=run1
> ```
>
> The SCHEDULER_DIR setting name is bound to change before the final
>   release, but  the idea will be the same - that you pass a directory
>   where to persist the  state.

Comment: You must use JOBDIR not SCHEDULER_DIR (see niko_gramophon's post below).

Answer (score 10):

Just wanted to share that feature is included in latest scrapy version, but parameter name is changed. You should use it like this:

```
 scrapy crawl thespider --set JOBDIR=run1
```

For more information here http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/jobs.html#job-directory

Comment: @niko_gramphon ,do you know if this restate the dupefilter state? and also do we need to add costume code if we're writing to a csv file and wanted just resume using the same file? thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Scrapy now has the working feature for this on their site documented here:

Here's the actual command:

```
scrapy crawl somespider -s JOBDIR=crawls/somespider-1
```